# is there a way to change the return value of a function without changing the function's body?

Tags: python

```
def f(x):
    return (x - 2)/2 
def g(x):
    return x
```

this code will do this:

```
func = g(f)
```

now func(1) = -1/2

what if I want to modify g(x) (and not f(x)) so that

```
func = g(f) 
func(1) = 1/2
```

is there a way to do this?

thank you 
Edit: f(x) can be any function that possibly returns a negative number

Comment: Make `g` return a function that returns 1/2.

Comment: maybe the return of g could be something like: return abs(x)?

Comment: the point is the function f(x) can be any function that returns a negative number

Comment: should have specified this in the description, sorry

Comment: and your intention is to return only positive values? If yes, the abs will solve that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a function *wrapping* another function. This can be done in Python using [decorators](http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/).

Given your function `f(x)`, let's say you'd like to receive the *negative* function value. And `f(x)` might be any function with any number of arguments. And possibly you don't really know `f(x)` at all.

Python's standard library comes with [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), which can be really handy in this case:

```
def g(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return -func_value
    return wrapper
```

Now the function `g(func)` returns a wrapper wrapping `func` post-processing its output:

```
>>> new_func = g(f)  # your original f(x)
>>> print(new_func(1))
0.5
```

This works with *any* function `func` with any number of positional or keyword arguments.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> def f(x):
...     return (x - 2)/2
...
>>> def g(function):
...     return lambda x: abs(function(x))
...
>>> func = g(f)
>>> func(1)
0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

for a generic application :

```
def absfunc(f):
    def absf(*args):
        return abs(f(*args))
    return absf

@absfunc
def f(x) :return (x-2)/2
```

`f(1)` is now  `0.5`.  You change the return value without changing the body neither the name.